# ADFS login challenge not triggered on media library deep links

Tags: federated-authentication, active-directory-module, adfs

We are currently using Federated Authentication with ADFS. The Identity Provider is OpenConnect.

Everything is working fine but now we came across a Problem below:

If you are not logged in and you open a media library deep link e.g.`https://intranet.mysite.com/-/media/intranetdocuments/document.pdf`
then I am redirected the no access page `https://intranet.mysite.com/sitecore/service/noaccess.aspx` Somehow ADFS challenge is completely ignored in such a case.

If I am logged in, the download of that document starts correctly as expected.
If I remove the /-/ from the Url it brings me to the login Screen or I will get at least a 404

I have really no idea what I could check or configure to get ADFS challenge triggering.

Comment: Is the PDF published? Are there any security settings on the media library item?

Comment: Sitecore will use `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler` for a request under `-/media` It sounds like this is not properly invoking the challenge whereas it does happen through the regular item resolution process. As a next step I would try to understand why the media request handler does not invoke the challenge.

Comment: The PDF is published, as I mentioned the download works fine if you are you logged in. Yes I noticed that I leave the actual site if the url begins with /-/ still no idea why the challenge does not invoke

Answer (score 1):

The way I handled this was by overriding Sitecore's existing `MediaRequestHandler`. Because I wanted it to handle the deep links for only one website, I wrote it like this, with the website in this case being `mysite.example.com`.

```
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Resources.Media;
using Sitecore.SecurityModel;
using System.Web;

namespace MyCompany.Handlers
{
    public class CustomMediaRequestHandler : MediaRequestHandler
    {
        public CustomMediaRequestHandler()
        {
        }

        protected override bool DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string itemNotFoundUrl;
            bool flag;
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");
            MediaRequest mediaRequest = MediaManager.ParseMediaRequest(context.Request);
            if (mediaRequest != null)
            {
                Media media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaRequest.MediaUri);
                if (media == null)
                {
                    using (SecurityDisabler securityDisabler = new SecurityDisabler())
                    {
                        media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaRequest.MediaUri);
                    }
                    if (media != null || (context.Request.Url.Host.Equals("mysite.example.com") && !Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated))
                    {
                        Assert.IsNotNull(Context.Site, "site");
                        itemNotFoundUrl = (Context.Site.LoginPage != string.Empty ? Context.Site.LoginPage : Settings.NoAccessUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        itemNotFoundUrl = Settings.ItemNotFoundUrl;
                    }
                    if (!Settings.RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(itemNotFoundUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Server.TransferRequest(itemNotFoundUrl);
                    }
                    flag = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = this.DoProcessRequest(context, mediaRequest, media);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                flag = false;
            }
            return flag;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in the web.config, I updated the handler to use my custom handler.

```
<add verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="MyCompany.Handlers.CustomMediaRequestHandler, MyCompany" name="Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler" />
```